# Why is DRF serializer returning errors with required fields?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

When I make a post request to register a user, the data sent is complete and in order, but the `RegisterationSerializer` serializer returns an error for the `username` and `password` fields. The error reads `This field is required.` for both fields.

My first guess was that the serializer is not receiving the data sent but that's false but the serializer receives the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Could the `validated_data` parameter in the `create` method not be populated. I tested it by printing it out on the terminal when making a request but it didn't print.

For the model, I'm using the built-in user model.

**Serializer**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class RegisterationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Registeration serializer"""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "password"]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):

        username = validated_data["username"]
        first_name = validated_data["first_name"]
        last_name = validated_data["last_name"]
        email = validated_data["email"]
        password = validated_data["password"]

        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )

        return user
```

**Views**

```
from authentication.serializers import RegisterationSerializer

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class RegisterationView(APIView):
    """Registeration View"""

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterationSerializer(data=request.data)

        # Generate tokens for existing users
        for user in User.objects.all():

            if not user:
                break
            else:
                try:
                    Token.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
                except Token.DoesNotExist:
                    Token.objects.create(user=user)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

            return Response(
                {
                    "user": {
                        "first_name": serializer.data["first_name"],
                        "last_name": serializer.data["last_name"],
                        "username": serializer.data["username"],
                        "email": serializer.data["email"],
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "message": "user created",
                        "code": status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    },
                    "token": token.key,
                }
            )

        return Response(
            {
                "error": serializer.errors,
                "status": status.HTTP_203_NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION,
            }
        )
```

Comment: FIrst guess is that you dont send this required fields in js request data. Show how do you send data at front site (js client, adroid ?).

Comment: Like mon io said, make sure you're sending the params correctly. If you're on Linux check out [httpie](https://httpie.io/) then you can simply post to your view from the command line like `http post 127.0.0.1:8000/register/ 'name=Freddy Mac' 'email=someemail@email.com'`

Comment: @beasyx, you're right. How silly of me. The error was in the way I was making the request. The JS Axios library converts the data to JSON implicitly but I did it explicitly first.

Comment: @monio Yeah, there was an error in the JS request data. I had to look into it to find out. Sorry for the trouble